# #sqlps - Problems connecting to the server to query

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, smo, sqlps

I'm trying to connect to a server\instance hosted remotely. The server is in a domain to which I'm connected as well (I'm able to login using SQL Server auth with the provided credentials from SSMS, locally)

```
Import-Module SQLPS

$query = 'select GETDATE() as date'

$op = invoke-Sqlcmd  -HostName 'servername' -Database  'DBName' -Username 'UN' -Password 'PWD' -Query "$query"

$op | Format-Table
```

Expected output woud be

```
2016-02-12 06:54:26.410
```

But what I get is

> PS SQLSERVER:> Import-Module SQLPS
>   $query = 'select GETDATE() as date'
>   $op = invoke-Sqlcmd  -HostName 'servername' -Database 'DBName' -Username 'UN' -Password 'Pwd' -Query "$query" #-IgnoreProviderContext
>   $op | Format-Table
>   WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'SQLPS' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
>   invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'UN'.
>   At line:3 char:7
>   + $op = invoke-Sqlcmd  -HostName 'servername' -Dat ...
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd],   SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
>
> invoke-Sqlcmd :
>   At line:3 char:7
>   + $op = invoke-Sqlcmd  -HostName 'servername' -Dat ...
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Can you all help me in finding what is this due to ?

Do I have to indicate anywhere that this is a SQL Server auth ?

Comment: In the title you mentioned an instance.  Though in you code example you don't mention an instance.  Is there an instance?

Comment: If you pass username/password, then this **is** SQL Server auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm guessing that you need to use the ServerInstance parameter instead of the HostName parameter.

```
Import-Module SQLPS

$query = 'select GETDATE() as date'

$op = invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Database 'DBName' -Username 'UN' -Password 'PWD' -Query "$query"

$op | Format-Table
```

Comment: Wow ! Thank you..  That worked
Technically, what difference dose it make ?